# Dual involution on the $Ext^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic curve over $\mathbb C$, and let $F$ be a vector bundle on it of degree $1$, take the dual of an extention $$0\rightarrow F^*\rightarrow E\rightarrow F\rightarrow0$$ is again an extension of $F$ by $F^*$, my questions are:

- How can I explicitly describe this involution on vector space $Ext^1(F,F^*)$?
- Are there any criterian for $E$ to be stable? ($F$ is taken to be semistable)

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure of an explicit involution, but certainly the involution need not be the identity (it seems that the sequence will be fixed by the involution if and only if there exists a skew-symmetric, nondegenerate pairing on $E$ such that the image of $F^*$ is Lagrangian).  One non-fixed example is the short exact sequence on $\mathbb{P}^1$, $$0\to \mathcal{O}(-3)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)\to \mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus 3}\oplus \mathcal{O}(3) \to \mathcal{O}(1)\oplus \mathcal{O}(3) \to 0.$$

Comment: One correction: actually, the fixed points will be those short exact sequences such that $E$ admits a nondegenerate pairing such that $F^*$ is isotropic and such that the induced pairing of $F^*$ with $F=E/F^*$ is the standard pairing.  However, there is no reason this pairing must be skew-symmetric.  It might be symmetric, for example.

Comment: If we suppose that $F$ stable then  $E$ is stable for all non trivial extension, Am I right?

Comment: "If we suppose that $F$ is stable then $E$ is stable for all non trivial extension ..."  Unfortunately this is not correct, for instance, on $\mathbb{P}^1$.  The semistable bundle $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2}$ is a nontrivial extension of $\mathcal{O}(+1)$ by $\mathcal{O}(-1)$.

Comment: Write $\mathrm{Ext}^1(F,F^*)=H^1(X, \mathcal{H}om(F,F^*))$. Then your involution is induced by the involution $u\mapsto {}^tu$ of $\mathcal{H}om(F,F^*)$ (this is true more generally for any extension of vector bundles over a scheme).